# Cannot resolve method 'setContentView' Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager'

Tags: java, android

В общем ,решил внедрить в приложение google карты через фрагменты,в конченом итоге получил 2 ошибки:"Cannot resolve method 'setContentView' Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager'",не могли бы вы подсказать примерные варианты их исправления?

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();



    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_news:
                    setTitle("Новости");
                    NewsListFragment fragment = new NewsListFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fram, fragment, "FragmentName");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();


                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_museums:
                    setTitle("Музеи");
                    MuseumsListFragment fragment1 = new MuseumsListFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.fram, fragment1, "FragmentName");
                    fragmentTransaction1.commit();


                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_map:
                    setTitle("Карта");


                    MapFragment fragment2 = new MapFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.fram, fragment2, "FragmentName");

                    fragmentTransaction2.commit();



                   return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        setTitle("Новости");
        NewsListFragment fragment = new NewsListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fram, fragment, "FragmentName");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

MapFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //getView();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Создание маркера и определение на карте
        LatLng Ural= new LatLng(56.841039, 60.622288);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Ural).title("---- \n"));

        LatLng ekaterinburg= new LatLng(56.837319, 60.605603);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ekaterinburg).title("--- \n"));


    }

    // ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.map_view)).setImageResource(R.drawable.tutor_ekb);


//    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.map_view)).setImageResource(R.drawable.tutor_ekb);
//        return convertView;
//    }




}
```

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2):

класс `Fragment` (и все его наследники) не имеют методов `setContentView()` и `getSupportFragmentManager()` - это методы класса `Activity` (и его наследников).

Разметка в фрагмент добавляется через инфлейт и возврат `View` в колбэке `onCreateView()`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}
```

то есть вызов метода `setContentView()` у вас просто лишний.

Управление фрагментом в фрагменте не очень хорошая идея, но чисто технически получить это можно так:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

На самом деле вам нужно видимо наследовать свой фрагмент от `SupportMapFragment` и вызывать его методы напрямую:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getMapAsync(this);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    }
}
```

хотя с картами я не работал.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

К ответу pvlofff могу добавить, в разметке xml файла надо указывать следующие:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

в самом фрагменте инитите карту:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_branch, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_branch_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}

 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap; // вот тут можно начинать работать с картой (что бы отработал этот колбек фрагмент должен implements OnMapReadyCallback)
    }
}
```

И не забудьте в манифесте указать ключ

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

[ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЯ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map?hl=ru)

Comment: Спасибо большое